# Awk is converting 'nan' to zeros

Tags: linux, awk, printf

I am attempting to preserve the 'nan's in an array of geophysical data.  I am using the following code as part of a linux string:

```
awk 'NR>50 {printf "(%d, %d, %d) %f %f %f %F\n",$1,$2,$3*10000,$4,$5,$7,$6}'<$PST
```

Why are the nan's getting converted to zeros?  How can I preserve the nan's in the original data?  I was told that it might have something to do with the lower-case letters of nan, as opposed to NAN or NaN?

Answer (score 2):

in awk, if we do math calculation on a Nan string, the string will be converted into zero, also for `printf`. see example:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{n="nan";printf "%d : %f : %s\n",n,n,n}'
0 : 0.000000 : nan
```

If you want to use `printf`, you need to define the format (`%s or %d/%f`) dynamically up to the `$1 ,$2 ...`. You can either check with regex, e.g. `"^[0-9.]+$" (it is not very strict to check number, just as example)` or compare to the `nan` like `tolower($1)=="nan"`.

you can also consider to first build the string (with checkings), then print it all at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using the posix version with gawk should work (following Kent's example)

```
gawk --posix 'BEGIN{n="NaN";printf "%d : %f : %s\n",n,n,n}'
```

prints out

```
nan : nan : NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

The word "NaN" is just a string like any other string. Treating it as anything else breaks historical awk script functionality.

Can you add a sign in front of it so gawk knows it's a number rather than a string?

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{n="NaN";printf "%d : %f : %s\n",n,n,n}'
0 : 0.000000 : NaN

$ gawk 'BEGIN{n="+NaN";printf "%d : %f : %s\n",n,n,n}'
nan : nan : +NaN

$ gawk 'BEGIN{n="-NaN";printf "%d : %f : %s\n",n,n,n}'
nan : nan : -NaN
```

Alternatively, using the `-M` option (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Gawk-and-MPFR) may be what you want:

```
$ gawk -M 'BEGIN{n="NaN";printf "%d : %f : %s\n",n,n,n}'
nan : nan : NaN
```

You could use `--posix` if all else fails, but that disables all of the very useful gawk-specific functionality (e.g. gensub()) so it's best avoided.